# Optional parameters and option types using F#

Tags: types, f#, option-type, optional-parameters

Consider the following code:

```
type Test () =
  member o.fn1 (?bo) = 1
  member o.fn2 (?bo) = o.fn1 bo

  member o.fn3 (?bo) = 1 + bo.Value
  member o.fn4 (?bo) = o.fn3 bo
```

While `fn1` and `fn2` work just fine, `fn4` produces the following error:

> init.fsx(6,30): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type int but here has type 'a option

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx#Y599) states:

> Optional parameters are interpreted as the F# option type, so you can query them in the regular way that option types are queried, by using a match expression with Some and None.

To me, optional parameters are not interpreted as the F# option type otherwise the code would compile. Moreover I do not understand why, when I hover over `?bo` in `fn3` the tooltip says `val bo: int option` but from outside expects only `int`. I would expect a behavior of accepting nothing, int, Some int and None. And as the last note, I do not understand why `fn2` works but `fn4` does not.

Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have to reconsider the correct answer. Based on this question (and answer):

[Propagating optional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095620/propagating-optional-arguments)

it seams that the correct answer is the following:

```
type Test () =
  member o.fn1 (?bo) = 1
  member o.fn2 (?bo) = o.fn1 bo

  member o.fn3 (?bo) = 1 + bo.Value
  member o.fn4 (?bo) = o.fn3 (?bo = bo)
```

It is a neat feature and credits for the answer go to [desco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270929/desco)!

Answer (score 5):

1. `fn2` works because `fn1` does not use its parameter, which is thus generic `'b option`.

   ```
   type Test () =
      member o.fn1 (?bo1) = 1  --> bo1: 'b option, here 'b = 'a option
      member o.fn2 (?bo) = o.fn1 bo  -->bo: 'a option
   ```
2. `fn4` complains that the parameter passed to `fn3` should be an int, but not `int option` because when you specify the parameter, you of course need to pass in a specific one. But you have the option to omit the parameter. The definition/type signature of `fn3` does not know whether you have specify `bo` or not, so it is a `int option`. Notice that you may have the following usage:

   ```
   type Test () =
      member o.fn1 (?bo) = 1
      member o.fn2 (?bo) = o.fn1 bo

      member o.fn3 (?bo) = 
      match bo with
        | Some v -> 1 + bo.Value
        | None -> 1

      member o.fn4 (?bo) = o.fn3()
   ```

where you don't specify the parameter for `fn3`, but when you specify it, it is a concrete `int`, not `int option`.

Think about a plotting function with three parameters:

```
let plot(?x,?y,?color)
```

because the parameters are optional, you can have the following usage:

```
plot(data)
plot(y=data)
plot(x=data, color='r')
```

But not:

```
plot(Some data)
plot(y=Some data)
plot(x=Some data, color=Some 'r')
```

Comment: I get your comment but I still don't like the way it is done. I would much more prefer to be able to send `nothing, value, Some value and None`. When I want to resend optional parameter from one member to another I have to pattern match it in the first member and call the second member with and without parameter or I have to define another member with option type and resend all members to this one.

Comment: optional parameter is a syntax that is friendly to library users, but not library writers. You stand on the library writers' point to judge this feature. The more dynamic the interface, the more checking in the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 2):

F# does not require matching to pass optional arguments.
Using the plot-example:

```
type Plotter() =
    static member Plot(?x,?y,?color) = 
        printfn $"{x}, {y}, {color}" // Do something "plottish" here

type PlotUser() =
    static member MyPlotUser(?x, ?y, ?color) =
        Plotter.Plot(?x = x, ?y = y, ?color = color)

/// Perform calls
PlotUser.MyPlotUser(10) // => Some(10), , 
PlotUser.MyPlotUser(10, color = "Green") // => Some(10), , Some(Green)
```

The above lets you call plot with your own optional arguments.
/JEE, Sharp#Soft