# Propagating optional arguments

Tags: inheritance, f#, optional-arguments

The following code does not compile.

```
type A(?arg) =
  member __.Arg : string option = arg

type B(?arg) =
  inherit A(arg) //ERROR expected type string but has type 'a option
```

I assume this is because an instance of the underlying type of the option must be provided, and the compiler handles passing `Some`/`None` based on syntax.

Assuming my assumption has been correctly assumed, is there a workaround for this? Is it possible to propagate optional arguments?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

F# spec 8.13.5 Optional arguments to method members

> Callers may specify values for optional arguments by using the following techniques:

- By name, such as arg2 = 1.
- By propagating an existing optional value by name, such as ?arg2=None or ?arg2=Some(3) or ?arg2=arg2. This can be useful when building one method that passes optional arguments on to another.
- By using normal, unnamed arguments matched by position.

  ```
  type A(?arg) =
      member __.Arg : string option = arg

  type B(?arg) =
      inherit A(?arg = arg) 

  printfn "1. %A" (B()).Arg // None
  printfn "2. %A" (B("1")).Arg // Some "1"

  printfn "3. %A" (A()).Arg // None
  printfn "4. %A" (A("1")).Arg // Some "1"
  ```

Comment: Okay. You've read way too much of the spec. :-) Why does this work?

Comment: Nevermind. I found it in the spec. I've _really_ got to read it some time.

Comment: Interesting that two months ago I had a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353897/optional-parameters-and-option-types-using-f/7102689#7102689) but nobody could give me the correct answer. Thanks desco for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry had to test it first: it seems you are right - you have to do the "?" for A yourself:

```
type A(arg : string option) =
  new (a) = new A(Some a)
  new () = new A(None)
  member __.Arg : string option = arg

type B(?arg) =
  inherit A(arg)
```

Comment: That's workable. Thanks. I'll wait and see if anyone can suggest how to make it work while retaining the optional args on `A`.

Comment: On second thought, this means optional args can't be propagated. You can't have a method or derived class with the same optional arg being passed to the constructor--kinda limiting. It would require branching to the correct constructor overload every time.

Comment: might be a bug - inside the type arg (with ?) is string option, but in the definition of new it's string - maybe we should file a case?

Answer (score -1):

F# will translate ?-marked arguments to optional values.
Providing an argument gives a Some-value while not providing it gives a None-value.
The combination of optional and named arguments lets you have huge flexibility.

See also my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66043023/15143713
/JEE, Sharp#Soft

Comment: The question is about how to propagate optional args to a base class. You merely pointed out something (the translation to Some/None) that was already stated in the question.

Comment: Please look at my link. I do explain how to propagate optional arguments there. I did not want to repeat my answer twice. /JEE - Sharp and Soft