# Is it possible to forward an optional argument in F#

Tags: f#, optional-parameters

I want to define an overloaded member function in F#

```
member o.m1(?x: int) =
    o.m1("bugs bunny", x) // <- error, expects a straight int, but x is int option

member o.m1(s: string, ?x: int) =
    42
```

but the code above fails. I can solve this so:

```
member o.m1(?x: int) =
    match x with
    | Some x -> o.m1("bugs bunny", x)
    | _ -> o.m1("bugs bunny")
```

I wonder if it is possible to avoid this switch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66501659/14134059

Comment: yes, thx. did not find it under that title. finally found it in the docs as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments#optional-parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by explicitly naming the optional parameter, like this:

```ml
    member o.m1(?x: int) =
        o.m1("bugs bunny", ?x = x)
```