# FakeItEasy - Invokes with option member arguments in F#

Tags: f#, fakeiteasy

When attempting to supply a fake delegate for a method with an optional parameter in a faked object

```
type MyType () = 
    abstract B: ?s:string -> unit
    default x.B (?s: string) = Option.iter (printfn "Implemented: %s") s

[<Property>]
let doit () = 
    let a = A.Fake<MyType>()
    A.CallTo(fun () -> a.B(ignored())).Invokes(fun s -> Option.iter (printfn "Faked: %s") s)
    a.B "Hello"
```

FakeItEasy complains

*FakeItEasy.Configuration.FakeConfigurationException: Argument constraint is of type System.String, but parameter is of type Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[System.String]. No call can match this constraint.*

Is there a way to make this run without changing the type definition ?

Comment: There's not quite enough information here to reproduce what you're seeing (at least for me). What is the definition of `ignored` in this example?

Comment: If I use `A<string>.Ignored` instead of `ignored()`, I get a different error: *An argument constraint, such as That, Ignored, or _, cannot be nested in an argument.*

Comment: The example is confusing for me because of the 2 types `A`. Maybe rename your A to MyExample?

Comment: Apologies on both fronts. I've updated the question to minimise confusion, and @Brian Berns you had the definition correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I was able to reproduce your error message by defining `ignored` as:

```ml
let ignored<'t> () = A<'t>.Ignored
```

The problem is that you've defined a string constraint for an argument that's actually a string option. You can work around this by explicitly naming the parameter `?s` when you call the member, like this:

```ml
A.CallTo(fun () -> a.B(?s=ignored())).Invokes(fun s -> Option.iter (printfn "Faked: %s") s)
```

Now the constraint has the correct type, `Option<string>`, and the code executes without error. Output is:

```
Faked: Hello
```

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7095907/344223) has more details about specifying values for optional arguments.

Comment: Genius and very much appreciated. Works like a treat